# Inject SecurityContext (similar as SecurityContextHolder from Spring)

Tags: jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey 2.27 on Google App Engine so I am also using the Objectify library which manages my entity classes. I want to be able to get the SecurityContext in one of those classes but Injecting it does not work since the POJO is not managed by Jersey itself.

Is their a way similar to Spring's way via SecurityContextHolder in Jersey 2.27?

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    ...
    private String modifiedBy;
    ...

    @OnSave
    private void onSave() {
        this.modifiedBy = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getUserPrincipal();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just pass the information down into the entity. The entity shouldn't know about about a SecurityContext (from a strictly design standpoint).

Comment: I agree I can change the signature of the onSave method to public void onSave(SecurityContext sc). However then I have to call the onSave manually and chances increase that I make an error and forget to call it somewhere before I do a save. I'd like to have similar functionallity like Spring's AuditorAware interface. Would using a Singleton created according to [this link](https://amiyasahu.github.io/singleton-class-per-thread-in-java.html) work when in the authentication filter I set the security context?